# Control dc-motor using H-Bridge and neopixel together with Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, neopixel

I am working on a project to control a DC motor rotation in forward and backward with an H-Bridge. And light up an adafruit neopixel same time when circuit turns on.

I made both things working separately. Now I combined the code but its not working as should. It works like the dc motor does one forward and back loop and  stops. Then the neopixel ring lights up. After some time when the neopixel code finishes, the dc motor does same one loop and this cycle continues.

I need help in making this code start dc motor working and neo pixel lighting same time.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN 6
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);


//DC motor
const int pwm = 3;  //initializing pin 2 as pwm
const int in_1 = 8 ;
const int in_2 = 7 ;

//For providing logic to L298 IC to choose the direction of the DC motor

void setup()
{
pinMode(pwm,OUTPUT) ;   //we have to set PWM pin as output
pinMode(in_1,OUTPUT) ;  //Logic pins are also set as output
pinMode(in_2,OUTPUT) ;

//Neopixel Ring
// This is for Trinket 5V 16MHz, you can remove these three lines if you are not using a Trinket
#if defined (__AVR_ATtiny85__)
  if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
#endif
  // End of trinket special code

strip.begin();
strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'


}

void loop()
{
//For Clock wise motion , in_1 = High , in_2 = Low

digitalWrite(in_1,HIGH) ;
digitalWrite(in_2,LOW) ;
analogWrite(pwm,255) ;

/*setting pwm of the motor to 255
we can change the speed of rotaion
by chaning pwm input but we are only
using arduino so we are using higest
value to driver the motor  */

//Clockwise for 3 secs
delay(1000) ;    

//For brake
digitalWrite(in_1,HIGH) ;
digitalWrite(in_2,HIGH) ;
delay(50) ;

//For Anti Clock-wise motion - IN_1 = LOW , IN_2 = HIGH
digitalWrite(in_1,LOW) ;
digitalWrite(in_2,HIGH) ;
delay(1000) ;

//For brake
digitalWrite(in_1,HIGH) ;
digitalWrite(in_2,HIGH) ;
delay(50) ;

//Neopixel Ring

// Some example procedures showing how to display to the pixels:
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50); // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50); // Blue
//colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255), 50); // White RGBW
  // Send a theater pixel chase in...
  theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50); // White
  theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 127), 50); // Blue

  rainbow(20);
  rainbowCycle(20);
  theaterChaseRainbow(50);
}

// Fill the dots one after the other with a color
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void rainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256; j++) {
    for(i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel((i+j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

// Slightly different, this makes the rainbow equally distributed throughout
void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256*5; j++) { // 5 cycles of all colors on wheel
    for(i=0; i< strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

//Theatre-style crawling lights.
void theaterChase(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {  //do 10 cycles of chasing
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, c);    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();

      delay(wait);

      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}

//Theatre-style crawling lights with rainbow effect
void theaterChaseRainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j < 256; j++) {     // cycle all 256 colors in the wheel
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, Wheel( (i+j) % 255));    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();

      delay(wait);

      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}

// Input a value 0 to 255 to get a color value.
// The colours are a transition r - g - b - back to r.
uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if(WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  }
  if(WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
  WheelPos -= 170;
  return strip.Color(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially every time you call delay, the arduino cannot do anything else. So you need to switch control to whatever else you wanted to be doing.

There are several approaches:

Timers - use a timer to update the state of one of your two tasks. This has the advantage that your tasks don't rely on the other to yield, but doesn't grow beyond a couple of tasks.

Software state machine - create a state machine for each task, and in the loop increment each state machine in turn. You'll want to create a structure to keep track of the state of the task, and each time you would call delay you'd instead update the structure and return. Usually you'd create a class for each task, as is done in [this Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/overview). This can be a lot of work, so there are libraries to do it for you.

Coroutines - these use a library to construct the state machines for you. e.g. http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=256256.0

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am reading basically adafruit link you put, still understanding. As there are two parallel tasks in my code, can you please edit my code so that both dc motor and neopixel work simultaneously. It will help me more to understand how it works for future work.